# Is it possible to use System.Drawing.Color with ViewBag in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I got a Viewbag in my controller how can I change text color without using CSS ? I have tried using System.Drawing.Color but color name is assigned to viewbag as a text. Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult change_color()
{

ViewBag.stackoverflow= "This text has to be red";

ViewBag.stackoverflow.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

return View()
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use CSS? This seems the incorrect way of styling text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use that enum with ViewBag. The reason is that ViewBag is just a placeholder for other objects, so it doesn't even make sense to assign that variable to that property, as the property `ForeColor` you are trying to access should be on the object you put into ViewBag to hold.

In the same sense, why not do

```
ViewBag.AnyNumber = 5;
ViewBag.AnyNumber.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

so you assign a color to a number (not text, number)?

You are basically trying to do an assignment to `string.ForeColor` which does not exist.

Comment: So is there any way to change viewbag text color in controller method ?

Comment: As I said, unfortunately no, it is not. There is no color property on a string object (when you do `ViewBag.stackoverflow= "Text"` its the same as doing `ViewBag.stackoverflow= new string("Text")` , you are creating a string object. In asp.net webforms, you create Label classes which do indeed have a color property you can manipulate.